# SwiftUI: Animating a transition between two views in a WindowGroup not working

Tags: swiftui

So I thought it would be easy to transition between the main view of an app and a settings view. The app code looks like this:

```swift
struct PointsMasterII: App {

    @StateObject var settings = AppSettings()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if settings.displaySettings {
                SettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(settings)
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(settings)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is pretty basic, in each of the views I have the following button defined:

```swift
@EnvironmentObject private var settings: AppSettings

var body: some View {

    // ...

    Button {
        withAnimation {
            settings.displaySettings.toggle()
        }
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "gearshape.2").font(.title)
    }
}
```

When I run the app and tap the button the two views switch as expected, but without any animation. I've tried a number of things but nothing seems to work and all the tutorials I've found on the interwebs say this should "just work".

Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no animation modifier, so no animation, try to wrap it in `Group` or some container (however more appropriate, from design perspective, to move all this into `ContentView` and separate alternates `MainView` and `SettingsView` there)

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Group {      // or VStack
        if settings.displaySettings {
            SettingsView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
                .transition(.slide)
        } else {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
                .transition(.slide)
        }
      }
      .animation(.default, value: settings.displaySettings)
    }
}
```

Comment: That got things working. But I've run into another issue. Whilst that animates between the two views. it's also triggering some unwanted animations in one of the views. So Now I need a way to say animate the switching of these two views, but not anything inside those views.